# Rails: How to find out which parent object has maximum children records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

These are the two models I am working with,

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

**Product model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

> Now I want to find out which user has maximum number of products.

I know I can find out by constructing a loop for users and associated products, but is there a way to find out by active record query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Product.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).order("count(user_id) desc").first.user` can be a solution